# Are there any open source libraries for drawing complex images in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4, drawing

Are there any libraries or tools that will help me draw something complex and still be able to use it in a flex project?

I talk about drawing with plain AS3 code.

I mean is there a certain opensource replacement for the `Graphics` class in AS3?

Comment: Drawings like a cars, animals etc.. i mean not basic stuff like rectangles , ellipses, GUI for short

Comment: Nop, my question was are there libraries for drawing with AS3 without using Flash IDE.

Comment: No, your question was "I mean is there a certain opensource replacement for the Flash IDE drawing environment?"

Comment: The Flash IDE doesn't draw at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand. How would you draw a car with code?

Comment: I've edited your question so it's more understandable - it's the `Graphics` class you are talking about, right?

Comment: You can draw shapes in Illustrator and export them as SWFs, and then load them at runtime.  Why do you want to avoid the Flash IDE?  Also, are you expecting this drawing API to be executed at runtime?

Comment: yup i can draw anything with as3 and i can use sprites which dont have timeline like movieclip. i can separate the code with classes and compile them and use them as sprites, but the problem is it is hard to draw complex drawings with code. in either case all vector shapes are code behind

Comment: i can even manipulate bitmap data with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). You can draw vector graphics with tools such as [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and display them in a flex project using [as3svgrendererlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/) for example. You can even SVG images using [svgeditor-as3](http://code.google.com/p/svgeditor-as3/).